# dropdownlist does not show any values after postback

Tags: asp.net

I've been battling with this issue for a couple of days now and would really appreciate if someone would shed some light for me.

I am populating a dropdownlist based on the selection from another dorpdownlist. As long as there is no postback happening, I see the list getting populated correctly but after a postback, my dropdownlist is empty.

At first, I was trying to manually set the Text property of the ddl but it kept giving me the following error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: ..ddl has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list

Then I read somewhere that I need to set the DataValueField property instead so I did that which got rid of the error but now I see the empty dll after a postback.
The ViewStateMode for the ddl is set to Enabled.

The two ddls I'm referring to are defined in a Formview in my .aspx file as ddlCompanyBuyerNVListInsert and ddlCompanyNameListInsert(I'm listing the Insert mode only). 
Based on the selections made in ddlCompanyBuyerNVList, I'm populating ddlCompanyNameList.

Here's the code behind for Page_Load and the functions that populate ddlCompanyNameList.

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        If NavHelper.User.UserName = "" Then
            Dim UserIP As String
            Dim UserLogin As String
            Dim UserEmail As String
            UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
            UserLogin = HttpContext.Current.Session("Username")
            UserEmail = HttpContext.Current.Session("Email")
            GetUserInfo()

            CurrentRFQ = Nothing
            If NavHelper.RFQ.ID = -1 Then
                formview_RFQ.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
                tabpanelCustomerParts.Visible = False
                tabpanelDocuments.Visible = False
                tabpanelReviews.Visible = False
                tabpanelRFQReviewHistory.Visible = False
                listview_CustomerParts.Dispose()

            Else
                formview_RFQ.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit)
                listview_ReviewContracts_Initial.EditIndex = 0
                SessionHelper.CurrentObject = TAA.Library.RFQ.GetObject(NavHelper.RFQ.ID)
                mRFQ = DirectCast(SessionHelper.CurrentObject, TAA.Library.RFQ)
                Dim UserdeptTotal As Long
                UserdeptTotal = HttpContext.Current.Session("DepartmentTotal")
                If formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList") IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList"), DropDownList)
                    FillCompanyNameDropDownList(ddl)
                End If
                tabpanelCustomerParts.Visible = True
                tabpanelDocuments.Visible = True
                tabpanelReviews.Visible = True
                tabpanelRFQReviewHistory.Visible = True
                If NavHelper.RFQ.Copy = True Then
                    SetModifyCopy()
                End If
            End If
        Else    'IsPostBack
            datasource_BuyerNVList.Dispose()
            datasource_RFQ.DataBind()
            datasource_RFQNote.DataBind()
            Dim ddl As DropDownList
            If (formview_RFQ.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Insert) Then
                ddl = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVListInsert"), DropDownList)
            ElseIf formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList") IsNot Nothing Then
                ddl = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList"), DropDownList)
            End If
            FillCompanyNameDropDownList(ddl)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Protected Sub FillCompanyNameDropDownList(ddlCompanyBuyerNamesList As DropDownList)
        Try
            Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DB.RFQconnection)
                cn.Open()

```
            Using cm As SqlClient.SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand

                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cm.CommandText = "GetCompanyNamesForThisBuyer"
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuyerName", (ddlCompanyBuyerNamesList.SelectedItem.Text))
                Dim ddlCompanyNamesList As DropDownList
                If (formview_RFQ.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Insert) Then
                    ddlCompanyNamesList = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyNameListInsert"), DropDownList)
                Else
                    ddlCompanyNamesList = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyNameList"), DropDownList)
                End If
                Using r As New SCF.Data.SafeDataReader(cm.ExecuteReader)

                    ddlCompanyNamesList.Items.Clear()
                    ddlCompanyNamesList.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select Company"))
                    While r.Read
                        Dim li As ListItem = New ListItem()
                        li.Value = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeInteger(r("CompanyBuyerId"))
                        li.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r("CompanyName"))
                        ddlCompanyNamesList.Items.Add(li)
                    End While
                End Using
                cm.Dispose()
                cn.Close()

                ' if more than one entry found, clear the company info fields until a selection is made
                If ddlCompanyNamesList.Items.Count > 2 Then 'because we've added a "Select Company" as the first item
                    ClearCompanyInfoFields()    ' company fields are text boxes that get cleared here
                    ddlCompanyNamesList.SelectedIndex = 0   
                End If
                ddlCompanyNamesList.Enabled = True
                If ddlCompanyNamesList.Items.Count = 2 Then        ' if only one entry found populate the compny info with that one entry's selection
                    ddlCompanyNamesList.SelectedIndex = 1
                    FillCompanyInfoFields(ddlCompanyNamesList)
                ElseIf ddlCompanyNamesList.Items.Count = 0 Then    ' if nothing found use the buyer list to populate company info fields
                    ddlCompanyNamesList.Items.Clear()
                    FillCompanyInfoFields(ddlCompanyBuyerNamesList)
                    ddlCompanyNamesList.Enabled = False
                End If

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        SetErrorPanel("An error occured during FillCompanyNameDropDownList.")
        Dim err As New HealthMonitoringCustomEvents.ErrorEvent("An error occured during FillCompanyNameDropDownList", Me, ex)
        err.Raise()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Protected Sub FillCompanyInfoFields(ddl As DropDownList)
        Try
            Dim buyerTitle As TextBox
            Dim buyerEmail As TextBox
            Dim buyerPhone As TextBox
            Dim buyerExt As TextBox
            Dim buyerMobile As TextBox
            Dim buyerFax As TextBox
            Dim CoAddr As TextBox
            Dim CoCity As TextBox
            Dim CoState As TextBox
            Dim CoZip As TextBox

```
        If (formview_RFQ.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Insert) Then
            buyerTitle = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerTitleInsert"), TextBox)
            buyerEmail = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerEmailInsert"), TextBox)
            buyerPhone = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerPhoneNumberInsert"), TextBox)
            buyerExt = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtExtInsert"), TextBox)
            buyerMobile = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerMobileNumberInsert"), TextBox)
            buyerFax = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerFaxNumberInsert"), TextBox)
            CoAddr = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyAddressInsert"), TextBox)
            CoCity = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyCityInsert"), TextBox)
            CoState = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyStateCodeInsert"), TextBox)
            CoZip = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyZipCodeInsert"), TextBox)
        Else
            buyerTitle = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerTitle"), TextBox)
            buyerEmail = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerEmail"), TextBox)
            buyerPhone = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerPhoneNumber"), TextBox)
            buyerExt = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtExt"), TextBox)
            buyerMobile = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerMobileNumber"), TextBox)
            buyerFax = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtBuyerFaxNumber"), TextBox)
            CoAddr = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyAddress"), TextBox)
            CoCity = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyCity"), TextBox)
            CoState = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyStateCode"), TextBox)
            CoZip = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("txtCompanyZipCode"), TextBox)
        End If

        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DB.RFQconnection)
            cn.Open()
            Using cm As SqlClient.SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cm.CommandText = "GetBuyerCompanyInfo"
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyBuyerId", (ddl.SelectedValue))
                Using r As New SCF.Data.SafeDataReader(cm.ExecuteReader)
                    ' populate company information fields in CurrentRFQ
                    While r.Read
                        CurrentRFQ.CompanyID = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(0))
                        CurrentRFQ.CompanyBuyerId = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(7))
                        ddl.DataValueField = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(1))
                        CoAddr.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(2))
                        CoCity.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(4))
                        CoState.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(5))
                        CoZip.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(6))
                        buyerTitle.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(9))
                        buyerEmail.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(10))
                        buyerPhone.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(11))
                        buyerExt.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(12))
                        buyerMobile.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(13))
                        buyerFax.Text = SCF.Data.SafeData.SafeString(r(14))
                    End While
                End Using
                cm.Dispose()
                cn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        SetErrorPanel("An error occured during FillCompanyInfoFields.")
        Dim err As New HealthMonitoringCustomEvents.ErrorEvent("An error occured during FillCompanyInfoFields", Me, ex)
        err.Raise()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And here's how the two ddls are defined in the .aspx file.

```
<td> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompanyBuyerNVListInsert" runat="server"
 AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="Input" 
 DataSourceID="datasource_BuyerNVlist" DataTextField="Key"  DataValueField="Value" 
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompanyBuyerNVListInsert_SelectedIndexChanged"
 ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="205px"> <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select
 Buyer" Value="0" /> </asp:DropDownList> </td> <td></td> <td class="style4"> Company:
 </td> <td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompanyNameListInsert" runat="server"
AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="Input"onselectedindexchanged="ddlCompanyNameListInsert_SelectedIndexChanged"
ViewStateMode="Enabled" Enabled="False"> </asp:DropDownList> </td>
```

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: please share your code so we can figure out what is going wrong .

Comment: did you forget to initialize the dropdown? if(!Page.IsPostBack){ // Initialize your dropdown }

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: I noticed that the contents of a text box inside the Formview that is filled at runtime also disappear after postback. 
I moved the ddl outside of the Formview and now it retains its contents after postback.
What is specific about controls inside a Formview that are filled at runtime and how can I make them retain their values after postback?